# Lag when using TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT

Tags: actionscript-3, text, textbox

I'm using the TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT event listener on a text box to split the entry in the box into an array of characters, but when I try to trace that array using the event listener it only displays the second-to-last character in the text box.

e.g:

I enter "hello", and output gives me "hell". I then change it to "helloq", and output gives me "hello".

How can I solve this? I've tried adding another one that only traces, but no difference. Thanks.

Code (searchBox is the text box, splitSearch is the array):

```
searchBox.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, splitBox);
function splitBox(e:TextEvent):void{
    splitSearch = searchBox.text.split("");
}
searchBox.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, split);
function split(e:TextEvent):void{
    trace(splitSearch);
}
```

Comment: Post some code please, we can't rectify it if we can't see it.

Comment: added code in main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the TEXT_INPUT event fires before the text field is updated. There are two ways to get the result you want. I think the easiest way is to listen to the text field for an Event.CHANGE event. If you really want to use TEXT_INPUT, you need to split the text field's characters, then push the character just entered by the user into the array. Both solutions work fine.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TextEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var searchBox:TextField;
        private var splitSearch:Array;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            searchBox = new TextField();
            searchBox.border = true;
            searchBox.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            addChild(searchBox);
            searchBox.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, splitBox);
            searchBox.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, split);

            searchBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onTxtChange);
        }

        private function splitBox(e:TextEvent):void{
            trace("splitBox() " + e.text + "  " + searchBox.text);
            splitSearch = searchBox.text.split("");
            splitSearch.push(e.text);
        }
        private function split(e:TextEvent):void{
            trace("split() " + splitSearch);
        }
        private function onTxtChange(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("onTxtChange() " + searchBox.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's helped me on two accounts, as I was looking around for a good example of adding events through .as files. It works perfectly, thanks!